# Black video when using PBJVideoPlayer on iOS 10

Tags: ios, avfoundation, pbjvision

I am using PBJVideoPlayer to show videos on my iOS app, using the following code:

```
_videoPlayerController = [[PBJVideoPlayerController alloc] init];
_videoPlayerController.delegate = self;
_videoPlayerController.view.frame = _playerView.bounds;
[self addChildViewController:_videoPlayerController];
[_playerView addSubview:_videoPlayerController.view];
[_videoPlayerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

_videoPlayerController.videoPath = [self finalVideoPath];
```

On about 50% of the time, the video is shown as black while the sound is fine.

The bounds are good (since I do see a black box) and the video path is good since I do have the correct video created.

I am using a device with iOS 10, and I still do not have a device with an older iOS to check..

Any ideas what might be the problem? I have seen other questions regarding black videos but non of them help.

Answer (score 0):

So, after several hours of investigating this, it seems to be an iOS10 bug.

See this: [AVPlayer playback fails while AVAssetExportSession is active as of iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560386/avplayer-playback-fails-while-avassetexportsession-is-active-as-of-ios-10)

What worked for me, is removing the watermark layer I had on the video and then removing the `animationTool` property from the video composition