# How to switch camera while video recording? (Ex: Snapchat, Facebook..etc)

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturesession, avcapture

I'm trying to switch camera while recording video like 'Snapchat' and 'Facebook' behavior. Switch camera work fine before start record video, but need to handle it separately when recording.

Any help appreciate...

```
public func switchCamera() {

        guard isVideoRecording != true else {
            //TODO: Handle switch camera when recording in here


            return
        }

        guard session.isRunning == true else {
            return
        }

        switch currentCamera {
        case .front:
            currentCamera = .rear
        case .rear:
            currentCamera = .front
        }

        session.stopRunning()

        sessionQueue.async { [unowned self] in

            // remove and re-add inputs and outputs
            for input in self.session.inputs {
                self.session.removeInput(input as! AVCaptureInput)
            }

            // add new input
            self.addInputs()

            self.session.startRunning()
        }

    }
```

Comment: checkout my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56572852/7090286

Answer (score -1):

You can try to write your frames with `AVAssetWriter`. [Here](https://github.com/piemonte/PBJVision) you can find an example.